# Are Sobolev trace spaces equal from both sides of the boundary?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces, traces, besov-spaces

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^n$ be a bounded open set and $\Omega'$ the complement of its closure.
Assume $\partial\Omega=\partial\Omega'$.
Are the quotient spaces $W^{1,p}(\Omega)/W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$ and $W^{1,p}(\Omega')/W^{1,p}_0(\Omega')$ bi-Lipschitz equivalent?
How much regularity do I need to assume for $\partial\Omega$ if this is false for general domains?

The two spaces are essentially function spaces on $\partial\Omega$, so identifying them is natural.
I have understood that both spaces coincide with the Besov space $B^{1-1/p}_{p,p}(\partial\Omega)$ if $\partial\Omega$ is Lipschitz, the quotient norm being bi-Lipschitz to the Besov norm.
However, I have never seen the bi-Lipschitz part explicitly stated, just equality of the spaces.
Equality of spaces often implicitly means comparable norms, but I want to be sure that this is actually the case if there is no citeable or doable proof without using the boundary Besov space.

Somewhat related: [Image of the trace operator](https://mathoverflow.net/q/70740/55893).

---

To clarify, the main question is this:
**Are the quotient spaces bi-Lipschitz equivalent?**
If necessary, you can assume that the domain is Lipschitz, but I am also interested in the more general case.
In the Lipschitz case the problem boils down to finding a reference to bi-Lipschitz equivalence to a Besov space.